External style library for Plasmo
I am trying to build browser extension with Plasmo, and I want to use control like react-quill, I can install the package, but it will also need to import the css for quill, in normal react project, we can import it like
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

But it did not work for plasmo, how to import external css for plasmo under Context UI?
